# @requestparam in spring is not working

Tags: spring, controller

i have been struggling with that for a couple of weeks now, i have the next method:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public ModelAndView update(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response,
    @RequestParam( value = "id", required = true ) String id ) throws Exception 
    {
        model = new ModelAndView( "/jspadmin/game/update" );

        getLog().error( "::: valor del string: " + request.getParameter( "id" ) );
        getLog().error( "::: valor del string: de ruta" + id );
     }
```

this code is inside a **multiactioncontroller** but i cant get the id value from @RequestParam anotation

i have anotation driven in **aplicationContext.xml**

im not using anotations at all, just in that method, i dont know if the controller needs a @Controller anotation mandatory to make work those anotations that are in the methods, i dont know what im missing, thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Do you have the `value` property of `@RequestMapping` set on controller level? And yes, `@Controller` is required on controller class.

Comment: i create the controller in xml, does matter if i put @controller in the class? because i get the next error:

Answer (score 2):

Try with @Controller annotation:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rootUrl")
public class MyController...
```

and action:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String update(@RequestParam...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code,just add value to some pattern in request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView update(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside Save id is " + id);
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```